# .htaccess Adding a trailing slash to requested files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been searching for almost 2 days now as to why this is not working for me. Lots of questions I've read about this have an answer to have a rewrite rule as follows:

`RewriteRule (.*)index/$ index.html [L,R=301]`

but that requires the user to manually append the trailing slash.

When a request comes in for `example.com/index` I want the URL to change in the clients browser to `example.com/index/`.

Also, if I manually append the trailing slash in the browser, I always get a 404 page not found error.  This makes complete sense as there is no file called index.html/. Is this a browser thing or can I achieve this through .htaccess rules?

So I want the user to request `example.com/index` which gets forwarded to `example.com/index.html` but displays `example.com/index/` in the browser. I want the slash as I think it makes it look much tidier.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your current code by this one in your htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^index/$ /index.html [L]
```

Note: you'll maybe have to clear your browser's cache since your old 301 rule may still be there

Comment: Perfect, Thanks! I had to disable MultiViews for this to work but I can just create my own rule to do what MultiViews does.